# How to debug pyqt signal/slot connections, probably threading issue

Tags: multithreading, connection, pyqt, signals-slots

I have the following piece of example code of my problem. Running this, I would expect that (if you type something in the lineedit) the A.updateValue slot would be called twice and thus show 'a.updatevalue called' and 'a2.updatevalue called'
However, it is only called once, namely for the self.a2 object and not for the self.a object, the latter which is sent from a worker thread to the GUI thread. How can I fix this so that this piece of code also triggers the slot for the self.a object?

Thank you,
David

```
import os, sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 

class A(QObject): 
    def __init__(self, name): 
        QObject.__init__(self) 
        self.name = name
    def updateValue(self, value): 
        print(self.name + ".updatevalue called")

class workerthread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
    def run(self):
        a = A('a')
        QObject.emit(self, SIGNAL("mySignal"), a)

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.hbox)

    def update(self, a):
        self.a = a
        edit = QLineEdit("", self)
        self.hbox.addWidget(edit)
        edit.textChanged.connect(self.a.updateValue)
        self.a2 = A('a2')
        edit.textChanged.connect(self.a2.updateValue)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Main()
    worker = workerthread()
    worker.connect(worker, SIGNAL('mySignal'), gui.update)
    worker.start()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `a` when you initialize `workerThread`

```
class workerthread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.a = A('a') 
    def run(self):
        QObject.emit(self, SIGNAL("mySignal"), self.a)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reaction. However, in my production code, there are multiple A objects, and I only know at runtime how many A's will be created, so defining all the A's at the creation of the workerThread is not an option. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I think the problem is that the 'self.a.updateValue' SLOT is not in the same thread as the 'textChanged' SIGNAL. Try adding this before `mySignal` is emitted: `a.moveToThread(QApplication.instance().thread())`